# Dynamic bean update once it has instantiated during the Spring Boot start up

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-bean

I am setting up a bean during the spring boot application startup. I am trying to update the bean using a rest endpoint. The end point in the controller calls the **updatePoints()**.  When I retrieve the data using GET point it still has only the data that was instantiated during the startup. It does not have the updated data inside the bean.

```
@Component
public class DynamicEntry{

private Map<String, DynamicPoint> dynamicPoints = new HashMap<>();
private DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@Autowired
public DynamicEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory){
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
}

@PostConstruct
 void loadPoints(){
        //load the dynamicPoints after the spring boots up
}

void updatePoints(String point){
try {
     if (!dynamicPoints.containsKey(point)) {
                DynamicPoint dynamicPoint = new DynamicPoint(point);
                beanFactory.registerSingleton(point, dynamicPoint);
                dynamicPoints(point, dynamicPoint);
}
} catch (Exception | Error e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Bean
    public Map<String, DynamicPoint> dynamicPoints() {
        return dynamicPoints;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try refreshing with [`ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--):

```
beanFactory.registerSingleton(point, dynamicPoint);
beanFactory.refresh();
```

but there will be side effects, e.g. recreation of existing singletons which may lead to your application downtime or response not being sent back to client.

What you are trying to achieve is very non standard. By design singleton bean definitions are processed during startup. You should rethink your approach and don't create singleton beans on the fly. Maybe you need a request or session scoped bean?

Comment: Is there any other way to update a bean that was instantiated during the start up?

Comment: @Harish you can get the existing bean instance with `@Autowired` and call a setter on it to change it's field value but creating a new bean is not recommend. It's probably doable but there is not enough information in your question to suggest a solution.

Comment: I tried using @Autowired for the existing bean instance and tried to add an entry to the map. The data was updated. but when i tried to retrieve the data it still showed me data at the time of spring boot instantiation.

Comment: @Harish please provide a working example to illustrate the problem, it's not clear from your question what exactly did you try.